# Python regex match month, date, time

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python and trying to make a simple but understandable regex to match a file containing these lines:

Month(2 letters), day and time

```
Sep 15 04:34:02
```

Regex so far:
I have managed to match the month, but dont know how to match the space and the digits. Hope someone can help me with this:

```
  with open('file.txt','r') as file:
            for line in file:
                    fil = re.findall('^\D{3}\d{1,2}',line)
                    print " ".join(fil)
```

Comment: Are all the lines like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
^\D{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{2}(:\d{2}){2}
```

**Explanation:**

- `\D{3}` any three non digits
- `\s+` one or more white spaces
- `\d{1,2}` one to two digits
- `\d{2}` exactly two digits
- `(:\d{2}){2}` two occurrences of (`:` followed by two digits)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG3hL2/12)

**Tip 1:** To make it more accurate replace `\D` with `[a-zA-Z]` because you dont want to allow any non digits here..

**Tip 2:** You would also want to use `[0-2]\d(:[0-5]\d){2}` for matching time..

**Final regex:**

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s+[0-2]\d(:[0-5]\d){2}
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I match this "sshd[12130]:" with digits inside?

Comment: `'^\D{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s+\li146-252\s+\[a-zA-Z]+\[\d+\]:\s+'` which is not maching this(its the last part which isn't matching: Sep 15 04:34:02 li146-252 sshd[12130]:

Comment: because your string is not having space at the end.. `\s+` (one or more white spaces) remove that.. or make it `\s*` (zero or more white spaces) and also you escaped `[` of `[a-zA-Z]` you shouldnt do it.. see `^\D{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s+\li146-252\s+[a-zA-Z]+\[\d+\]:`

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
[A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{1,2}\s(?:\d{1,2}:){2}\d{1,2}
```

`[A-Za-z]{3}` -> three letters -> Sep

`\s` -> space

`\d{1,2}` -> two digits -> 15

`\s` -> space

`(?:\d{1,2}:){2}\d{1,2}` -> time -> 04:34:02

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oJ1rA3/1)